# AnkhSVN keeps marking .designer.cs files as newly added

Tags: c#, svn, visual-studio-2013, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Since I upgraded from VS2012 to VS2013 I have an issue with my AnkhSVN plugin. Every time there is a change in a .designer.cs file this file will get marked as "new" instead of "changed". If I try to make a commit it will say that the file is already under version control and can not be added and then it completely breaks everything. This behaviour is somehow new in combination with VS2013. I tried to both upgrade my TortoiseSVN client as well as my AnkhSVN plugin to the latest version but the bug persists. 
Did anyone else experience this issue? A colluege of mine has the same problem with this setup . For now we switched back to VS2012 because of this but that's a rather poor solution regarding how much VS2013 costed.

I am very grateful for any help.
Have a nice day
Oli