# File is marked as "New" instead of "Modified" by AnkhSvn

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

I have one specific file (Web Forms Master Page) in my Visual Studio 2013 project that gets incorrectly marked as "New" when it is modified. It is not new, it already exists in the project and Subversion repository. I use AnkhSVN as Source Control Provider.

If I modify file outside Visual Studio (say, in Notepad++) it is displayed as modified in Windows Explorer (I also have Tortoise SVN installed) and I can commit my changes using TortoiseSVN.

I also tried checking out whole project from repository to another local folder and the problem remains.

How can this be fixed? I found similar post on SO ([AnkhSVN keeps marking .designer.cs files as newly added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500079/ankhsvn-keeps-marking-designer-cs-files-as-newly-added)) but it has no answer.

Comment: If TortoiseSVN is a newer version than AnkhSVN (assuming both are installed on the same machine), the top answer on this question may help explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695136/why-are-all-files-in-ankhsvn-solution-marked-as-new-after-installing-tortoisesvn

Comment: The linked you posted has to do with subversion switching to new local copy format some time ago. This is not the case for my situation.

Comment: In that case I'm wondering if it's a case changed issue possibly? I know Subversion is case sensitive (though windows isn't), not sure about ankhsvn - but has the case been changed in any of the filenames that are showing as new instead of modified?

Comment: I think this it! Locally the file is called Somefile.master and in repository it is Somefile.Master - file extenstion is capitalized in repository (as it should be). It is also referenced as lowercase in .CSPROJ file (and another Master file that I have no problems with is referenced as .Master, with uppercase). I am not sure exactly how/when it was changed. Is there a way I can fix it without breaking the change log?

Comment: Using the command line `svn rename` to rename the file to what ankhsvn expects it to be should sort it? You can't use windows to rename it as it's not case sensitive so won't actually record a change, whereas svn rename should do.

Comment: Yes, that was it. This is how I fixed it: locally I had Somefile.Master (and related files files like SomeFile.Master.cs, SomeFIle.Master.Designer.cs) correctly named. I then closed my solution in Visual Studio, opened .CSPROJ file in Notepad++ and replaced all .master with .Master and committed change via TortoiseSVN. I then opened solution in Visual Studio, changed file in question and it was correctly marked as "Modified" as opposed to "New". So it looks like Ankhsvn IS case sensitive and TortoiseSVN isn't.

Comment: So what was happenning when I made change in SomeFile.Master it would get saved as SomeFile.master because this is how .CSPROJ had it named and it would cause problems

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: Will you post your suggestion as an answer so that I can mark it as such and you will get points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if it's a case changed issue possibly? I know Subversion is case sensitive (though windows isn't), not sure about ankhsvn - but has the case been changed in any of the filenames that are showing as new instead of modified?

If so, using the command line `svn rename` to rename the file to what ankhsvn expects it to be should sort it? You can't use windows to rename it as it's not case sensitive so won't actually record a change, whereas svn rename should do.

Comment: Yes, that was it but I haven't used SVN RENAME to fix it. This is how I fixed it: locally I had Somefile.Master (and related files files like SomeFile.Master.cs, SomeFIle.Master.Designer.cs) correctly named. I then closed my solution in Visual Studio, opened .CSPROJ file in Notepad++ and replaced all .master with .Master and committed change via TortoiseSVN. I then opened solution in Visual Studio, changed file in question and it was correctly marked as "Modified" as opposed to "New".